# How many ways to calculate the FPS (Frames per second) of an iOS App programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect, frame-rate, cadisplaylink

Since we are talking about `programmatically`, **Instruments** are not under my consideration.

Some reference listed in advance:

- [Calculate fps (frames per second) for iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1738315/889538)
- [Display FPS on iOS onscreen (without Instruments)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15169342/889538)
- [At what framerate does the iOS UI run animations at?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25118875/889538)

## 1. Using [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/index.html)

According to the doc,

> The duration property provides the amount of time between frames. You
>   can use this value in your application to calculate the frame rate of
>   the display...

So in my demo project, I add a displayLink to mainRunLoop for UITrackingRunLoopMode:

```
self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(screenDidUpdated)];
[self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];
```

and use `duration` to calculate FPS. But out of my expectation, the `duration` is always 0.016667 (~ FPS 60) not matter the tableView scrolls smoothly or not.

How I make the tableView lag is to add one line in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Then I turned to `displayLink.timestamp`, and it worked.

## 2. Observing `drawRect:`?

My second idea is to observe `drawRect:`, I thought when the tableView scrolls, its `drawRect:` would be called frame by frame, then I could calculate the FPS according to the time diff between `drawRect:` callings.

But it failed, cause the `drawRect:` was called only once (while cells for many times). This way is similar to `Using CADisplayLink`, but maybe I chose the wrong position/method(like `drawRect:`) to observe, any recommended method for me to observe?

## Questions:

1. How the Instruments measure the FPS accurately?
2. Is the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/index.html) said `using duration to calculate FPS` wrong?
3. What's the right/best method to observe to calculate the FPS?

Thanks!

Comment: What sort of App?  One using UIKit or OpenGL?

Comment: are you running on a device or the simulator?

Comment: Simple, you declare NSTime object for 1 sec and make a counter to measure number of frames.

Comment: @trojanfoe Using UIKit. BTW, what's the difference?

Comment: @madmik3 For now, on the simulator.

Comment: @user3833571 The point is how to measure the number of frames per second.

Answer (score 3):

As [the documentation for CADisplayLink states](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/index.html), `duration` is basically just `1 / maximumFramesPerSecond`. You need to check the discrepancy between `targetTimestamp` and `timestamp` to detect dropped frames:

> The duration property provides the amount of time between frames at the maximumFramesPerSecond. To calculate the actual frame duration, use targetTimestamp - timestamp.

Comment: targetTimestamp is only available on iOS 10.0

Answer (score 1):

This works but requires some setup.

1. Set up a CADisplayLink and leave the frameInterval as the default (shoots once per frame)
2. This CADisplayLink needs to actually be added to a runLoop and fire at least once to get to #3
3. Once that calls back, or inside the callback, you can get the frame rate. Here's some Swift code to give you the idea, but where `displayLink` is your CADisplayLink instance

   ```
   var framesPerSecond : Int {
       var retVal : Int = 60 // default value, just in case link.duration is still 0 
       if let link = displayLink where link.duration > 0 {
           retVal = Int(round(1000 / link.duration)/1000)
       }
       return retVal;
   }
   ```