# iOS : WHO'S in charge of refreshing UI/Screen while UITableView's scrolling?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uikit, drawrect

I was finding ways to calculate FPS as [what I said here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26888434/889538), holding the idea that when the UITableView scrolls, its `drawRect:` would be called frame by frame. But it didn't.

The UITableView's `drawRect:` will be called only once, not matter I drag it up and down quickly or put buttons on it. So does the UITableView's superview and cells. All the UIViews' `drawRect:`s are called only once for each.

Given that `drawRect:` called only once, WHO is in charge of refreshing UI/Screen while UITableView's scrolling?

## UPDATED 1

> I know UITableView's delegate & dataSource are responsible for layout
> cells to show. But what if tableView just scrolls slightly? Though its
> delegate & dataSource are not called, the screen's content still
> changed. On this occasion, who is up to the UI refresh on iPhone
> screen? scrollView scrolled -> UIKit -> GPU -> LCD Screen?

Comment: You can use Scroll view delegate methods, thew will get called when you scroll up or down. Based on that Pull to refresh works :)

Comment: There's a uiscrollview (somewhere) above the table view. Not quite sure how you'd hook into it, but that class will send messages on scrolling.

Comment: @AnnaDickinson `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Oh, right.  So, you can set the delegate and override the -scrollViewDidScroll method in a custom UITableView class.

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota so you mean I can calculate FPS via observing scrollViewDidScroll: ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `UITableView`'s `dataSource` and `delegate` properties are for. They allow you to define who is in charge of setting up the UI and handling user interaction.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Of course I know UITableView's delegate & dataSource are responsible for layout cells to show. But what if tableView just scrolls slightly? Though its delegate & dataSource are not called, the screen's content still changed. On this occasion, who is up to the UI refresh on iPhone screen? scrollView scrolled -> UIKit -> GPU -> LCD Screen?

Comment: All iOS UI eventually breaks down to OpenGL ES calls/objects. `UIView`s have their corresponding `CGLayer`s, which get rendered in OES in some way or another. When you change the transform of a view (by translating/moving, rotating, scaling, skewing, etc.) you also update its OES representation. OES will call the drawing method on its objects on each draw loop, which I think is what you're looking for, but it's abstracted away from you. `drawRect:` methods only get called when `setNeedsDisplay` is called, which is minimised for performance sake.